# Ghostscript - Specify output size when creating png from pdf

Tags: pdf

I've read a few threads on this general subject, but they don't seem to help so I'm asking as a new question.

I'm currently creating a process to use ghostscript from vb.net (I've had some issues with parameters with Ghostscipt.net, but external process works well enough for me)

I'm capturing a small square area from a specific page of a pdf and converting to a png. There's an offset involved as the area is not on the left/bottom edge, so I'm using 200x200 for the size and -220, 206 for x/y offset and I've specified page 1 for this example, as below:

```
" -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pnggray -r600 -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=200 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=200 -dFIXEDMEDIA -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -SOutputFile="mypath\output.png" -c "<</PageOffset [-220 206]>> setpagedevice" -f "mypath\input.pdf"
```

This works fine, but I next need to restrict the output png file to 600 x 600 pixels, regardless of input size.

All the solutions I've found seem to be related to changing device width/height points, but I use those to specifiy the area I want to capture, so I'm confused as to how this should work.

Can anyone help?

Sorry I couldn't tag this for Ghostscript - my reputation isn't high enough!

Thanks

Comment: Hi - thanks for reply. I think I'm getting confused with how I need to specify the crop area - as you suggested, setting 72 for DEVICEWIDTHPOINTS and DEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS gets me to a 600 pixel square output file, but I'm not seeing the whole of the graphic I want to capture, so I need to expand the crop area - I mistakenly thought that was done via the devicepoints parameters.

EDIT- actually that can't be right - I need to scale it instead?

Comment: Thanks - no wish to play with the media boxes, so I'll try adjusting the offset. Unfortunately a lot of this is trial and error and I don't really understand what I'm doing!

Comment: Sorry, Im just confused! - I've added a link to the pdf I'm working with to my main question. If I use -r600 and devicewidth height/width of 200 I capture the QR code I want in a 1667 pixel square file. If I go to -r300 I get 833 pixel square file, which is acceptable, but I think need to achieve -r600 for the QR library I'm using to be able to handle the decoding.

Comment: Thanks for looking at the pdf, your comments are appreciated - it was put together by one of my colleagues, so I'll check with him. It is meant to be just a proof so that may be the reason there are some oddities, but I'll ask about the issues you found.

Comment: Will do. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks K J for your comments, very helpful. I've been testing an alternative library for decoding the QR codes - ZXing.net - and this seems not to be so fussy about resolution and image size, so I think I've gotten around the problem that way.

I've tried it with both 300 and 600 resolution files of different sizes and it's worked well, so I'd recommend it to anyone with this sort of requirement!